# Download Android source with cygwin does not work

Tags: android, android-source, repo

I'm trying to download the Android sources as described here: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html#getting-the-files

```
wutze@wutze-pc ~
$ cd bin

wutze@wutze-pc ~/bin
$ ls

wutze@wutze-pc ~/bin
$ cd ..

wutze@wutze-pc ~
$ PATH=~/bin:$PATH

wutze@wutze-pc ~
$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 26223  100 26223    0     0   107k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  110k

wutze@wutze-pc ~
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo

wutze@wutze-pc ~
$ mkdir WORKING_DIRECTORY

wutze@wutze-pc ~
$ cd WORKING_DIRECTORY

wutze@wutze-pc ~/WORKING_DIRECTORY
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle

wutze@wutze-pc ~/WORKING_DIRECTORY
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle

wutze@wutze-pc ~/WORKING_DIRECTORY
$
```

but I'm not getting asked for credentials, and repo sync won't work either:

```
wutze@wutze-pc ~/WORKING_DIRECTORY
$ repo sync
error: command 'sync' requires repo to be installed first.
         Use "repo init" to install it here.

wutze@wutze-pc ~/WORKING_DIRECTORY
```

and I don't get any error message

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Git for Cygwin. Its under the 'devel' category within Cygwin setup.
The only way you can add these is by re-running the setup again.